# Getting the last element of an array in CoffeeScript

Tags: arrays, coffeescript

Is there a quick (short, character wise) way to get the last element of an array (assuming the array is non-empty)?

I usually do:

`last = array[array.length-1]` or `last = array[-1..][0]`

Comment: `last = array.pop()` or `last = arr.slice().pop()` if you *don't* want to remove that element from the array.

Comment: For a succinct solution, I recommend `last = (function (arr) {return arr.splice(-1, 1)[0];}).apply(null, [Array.prototype.slice.call(array, 0, array['length'])]);`.

Comment: @Lchi do you want a copy of the array's last value, or do you want the last element of the array if, e.g., you want to modify it?

Comment: @Snowball I'm going to assume that's a bit of javascript humor.

Comment: Just the last element (not a copy), without removing it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**If you're using a modern version of CoffeeScript, do not use this. Use the answer by *dule* instead.**

---

If you don't mind modifying the array,

```
last = array.pop()
```

If you don't want the array modified,

```
last = array[..].pop()
```

That compiles to `last = array.slice(0).pop()`. I think it's pretty readable to people already exposed to CoffeeScript or Python slices. However, keep in mind that it will be much slower than `last = array[array.length-1]` for large arrays.

I wouldn't recommend `last = array[-1..][0]`. It's short, but I don't think its meaning is immediately obvious. It's all subjective, though.

Comment: It should be noted that array.slice(0).pop() creates an entirely new array, just to get the last element. I would suggest dule's suggestion below.

Comment: @HasFiveVowels: Agreed. At the time, CoffeeScript didn't support that syntax. I've updated my answer to point future readers to dule's answer instead.

Answer (score 20):

It's easy and harmless to modify the `Array` prototype for this:

```
Array::last = -> @[@length - 1]
```

If you're already using the excellent [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), you can use its `_.last(arr)`.

Answer (score 19):

Another alternative is to use coffee's destructuring:

`[..., last] = array`

Answer (score 9):

I like dule's suggestion, here is why:

I tested this destructuring method with 'try coffeescript', an online coffee to js compiler at http://coffeescript.org/.

Given the following coffeescript:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

[..., last] = arr
```

It compiles into:

```
var arr, last;

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

last = arr[arr.length - 1];
```

This is really ideal. The destructuring syntax is quite clear and concise. The compiled javascript is performant. I see no reason to not use this.

(I do not have enough reputation to post this as a comment under dule's answer, so I added it as an answer even though it is a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do this:

```
last = array[-1..][0]
```

Comment: You are missing [0] in the end as in `last = array[-1..][0]`. Also it generates to `slice(-1)` which is slow.